# How can I extract all the data from a JSON containing multiple arrays?

Tags: javascript, json

How can I extract all the numbers from this JSON in a set, in JavaScript?

```
[
  {
    "name": "list0",
    "list": [0,1,2,3,4]
  },
  {
    "name": "list1",
    "list": [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  }
]
```

I'd like to get a set with only:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate multiple array of objects into one and use outside of function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58478420/concatenate-multiple-array-of-objects-into-one-and-use-outside-of-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

> The `Set` object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references.

and [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

> The `flatMap()` method first maps each element using a mapping function, then flattens the result into a new array. It is identical to a map() followed by a flat() of depth 1, but `flatMap()` is often quite useful, as merging both into one method is slightly more efficient.

```js
var arr = [
  {
    "name": "list0",
    "list": [0,1,2,3,4]
  },
  {
    "name": "list1",
    "list": [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  }
]

var res = [... new Set(arr.flatMap(el => el.list))];
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array.reduce` and spread operator:

```js
let input = [
  {
    "name": "list0",
    "list": [0,1,2,3,4]
  },
  {
    "name": "list1",
    "list": [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  }
];

let numbers = input.reduce((acc,cur) => [...acc, ...cur.list], []);
console.log(numbers);

console.log(...new Set(numbers))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the spread **...array** operator to solve the problem.

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "name": "list0",
    "list": [0,1,2,3,4]
  },
  {
    "name": "list1",
    "list": [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  }
] 

let a = [];
arr.forEach(obj=>{
    a.push(...obj.list)
})

const set = new Set([...a]);
console.log(...set)
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and `flat` to iterate through the array and convert it to one level array or [flatmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to do both at the same time and then you use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to deduplicate

```js
array=[ { "name": "list0", "list": [0,1,2,3,4] }, { "name": "list1", "list": [3,4,5,6,7,8,9] } ]
set=[...new Set(array.map(x=>x.list).flat())]
console.log(set)
```

using `flatmap()`

```js
array=[ { "name": "list0", "list": [0,1,2,3,4] }, { "name": "list1", "list": [3,4,5,6,7,8,9] } ]
    set=[...new Set(array.flatMap(x=>x.list))]
    console.log(set)
```